# How to extract green channel using opencv in python?

Tags: python, opencv3.0, extract

For extracting green channel from a RGB image, i have done the following code but this is not working

```
import cv2
green_image = cv2.imread('eye.jpg')
green_image[:,:,0] = 0
green_image[:,:,2] = 0
cv2.imshow('G-RGB', green)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The code has raised an error:

```
TypeError

   1 import cv2
   2 green_image = cv2.imread('eye.jpg')
-->3 green_image[:,:,0] = 0
   4 green_image[:,:,2] = 0
   5 cv2.imshow('G-RGB', green)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: try making a copy first? `rgb_image = cv2.imread('eye.jpg') green_image = rgb_image .copy()` and then try saving it uhm, like `imsave("green_output_image.jpg",green_image)`

Comment: Make sure you have `eye.jpg` in current directory.

Comment: It is not working. Showing error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'`

Comment: `cv2.imshow('G-RGB', green)` shouldnt that be `cv2.imshow('G-RGB', green_image)` instead?

Comment: Thanks both of you Sociopath and user5173426. It is now working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
cv2.imshow('G-RGB', green)
```

to

```
cv2.imshow('G-RGB', green_image)
```

Hence:

```
import cv2
rgb_image = cv2.imread('eye.jpg')
green_image = rgb_image.copy()
green_image[:,:,0] = 0
green_image[:,:,2] = 0
cv2.imshow('G-RGB', green_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

OUTPUT:
[image: geen]

Comment: There was a mistake in image directory and variable name in my code. Nowthis is working

Comment: @Nur_Alam39 Glad you worked it out, if this answer helped you can accept it to close the question, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`cv2.split`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cv2.split#cv2.split) to split blue, green, and red channel.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('eye.jpg')
b, g, r = cv2.split(img)
cv2.imshow('green', g)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```